# Can't display all description.StringBuffer capacity?

Tags: android, textview, stringbuffer

I want to read an RSS feed on my app, i have been based on some guides, and i succeed to implement the basics. However, when i open an RSS item, the title is showen, but the description(that have more caracters) ends with some 13 lines and three points(...). I've read in JAVA doc that StringBuffer has a limited capacity, and when it arrives on its full capacity it sets a points. That why i think that the problem comes from StringBuffer:

```
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // Nous réinitialisons le buffer a chaque fois qu'il rencontre un item
            buffer = new StringBuffer();        

            // Ci dessous, localName contient le nom du tag rencontré

            // Nous avons rencontré un tag ITEM, il faut donc instancier un nouveau feed
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){          
                this.currentFeed = new Feed();
                inItem = true;
            }

            // Vous pouvez définir des actions à effectuer pour chaque item rencontré
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
                // Nothing to do    
            }
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)){
                // Nothing to do    
            }
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(PUBDATE)){   
                // Nothing to do    
            }
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(CREATOR)){
                // Nothing to do
            }
            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){

            }
        }

@Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {     

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
            if(inItem){             
                // Les caractères sont dans l'objet buffer
                this.currentFeed.setTitle(buffer.toString());               
                buffer = null;
            }
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)){
            if(inItem){             
                this.currentFeed.setLink(buffer.toString());                
                buffer = null;
            }
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(PUBDATE)){   
            if(inItem){             
                this.currentFeed.setPubDate(buffer.toString());             
                buffer = null;
            }
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(CREATOR)){
            if(inItem){             
                this.currentFeed.setCreator(buffer.toString());             
                buffer = null;  
            }
        }
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
            if(inItem){             
                this.currentFeed.setDescription(buffer.toString());             
                buffer = null;
            }
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){      
            feeds.add(currentFeed);
            inItem = false;
        }
    }

    // * Tout ce qui est dans l'arborescence mais n'est pas partie  
    // * intégrante d'un tag, déclenche la levée de cet événement.  
    // * En général, cet événement est donc levé tout simplement 
    // * par la présence de texte entre la balise d'ouverture et 
    // * la balise de fermeture

    public void characters(char[] ch,int start, int length) throws SAXException{        
        String lecture = new String(ch,start,length);
        if(buffer != null) buffer.append(lecture);              
    }


    // cette méthode nous permettra de récupérer les données
    public ArrayList<Feed> getData(){
        return feeds;
    }
}
```

Any help please? Thank you very much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
    <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/tv_title" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/tv_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/tv_date" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the URL to your RSS feed?

Comment: @kabuko: http://feeds.feedburner.com/Frandroid

Comment: That's clearly ellipsized at the source. Apparently Chrome does something special to fetch the full article and that might be what you're seeing and thinking it's not truncated, but if you look at view-source:feeds.feedburner.com/Frandroid you can see that it is.

Comment: Strange :\ any idea of how solving the problem? Just launch the rss item in the browser?

Comment: You could get the original link as it's supplied in the `<feedburner:origLink>` tag and pull down that, but you'll have to deal with HTML then.

Comment: @kabuko: what about changing the whole storing structure (in place of StringBuffer i use other structure).  But you have said that it's due to XML! Okay, i have to find other solution like your proposed one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `StringBuffer` has no such behavior. You're probably using a `TextView` and have the [`ellipsize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) attribute set or your feed data actually is truncated and ellipsized itself. Take a look at the RSS feed directly in a browser to see if it is.

Comment: Please see the posted XML, i think that it have not something "strange", no?

Comment: And it is truncated and ellipsized itself :\? (i've seen the RSS feed in the browser and in my app it misses alot of caracters)